# Drawing lines between points in a shapefile that are related to each other

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

This is a more general question, wondering if it is possible. I want to make a map of all the organizations in my city and which ones partner together. I imagine I would make a shapefile that is a list of all the organizations, and then in in the attribute table, stretch that same list across the fields, making each field the name of one of the organizations. And then for each organization that partners with another one, I could indicate that with a value. (Just to clarify, lets say organization A partners with organizations B and D. Looking along the row for the attributes of A, there would be a value in field B and D). But is it possible to display those connections on a map with lines between the organizations that partner together? So that on the map there would be a line between A and B, and another between A and D? Or is there a different way I should go about this completely?

Comment: I can think of two tools you could possibly use. One is the `join by lines (hub lines)` tool, which will draw lines from points in a hub layer to points in a spoke layer. The other is the `geometry by expression` tool which will create geometries based on an expression written by you.

Comment: I will look into those, thanks!